# Prettier - Code formatter does not works properly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

already i work in vs-code it formats perfectly manual format as well as format on save once  i change my laptop i configure all the things perfectly and it does not format

Answer (score 0):

How I've sorted it after having super huge frustrations with Prettier stopping working in VSCode.

```
1. Select VS Code -> View -> Command Palette, and type: Format Document With
2. Then Configure Default Formatter... and then choose Prettier - Code formatted.
```

This sorted the problem for me magically.

Depending on your case this might help you...

Comment: thanks but i already configured everything but after all that it does not work